# IID noise assumption at Matched Filter sample time

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, digital-communications

I read that at the correct sample times of a matched filter output the noise is independent assuming a Nyquist pulse.

Can someone provide a proof of this or explain it more? Assuming your matched filter duration had a longer duration than your sample period, it seems the sample noise should be correlated.

Why is this not the case?

Comment: There's quite a bit of *context* missing for that statement, it's not generally true. Can you share the full sentence/paragraph this is from?

Comment: Ok, I read as follows: assuming IID additive white gaussian noise the noise output of the matched will be independent when sampled at the correct sampling times(assuming a Nyquist pulse for example). Logically it doesn't seem correct since your matched filters duration will longer than your sample period.

Comment: *assuming a nyquist pulse* is kind of important here. Please edit your question to include the *whole* paragraph, not just this sentence.